# Hide an object from reflecting in the ocean modifier

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection, ocean-simulation

I'm new to Blender and just following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsETUAsiI7c).

I wanted to put a bit of my own stamp on it and got this grid set up at the top to give it an 80s vibe:

[image: screenshot]

But its making a mess of my ocean.

I want to have the pink grid object in the top to be hidden from being reflected in the ocean modifier plane below.

I tried searching and looking for how to hide an object, turn off the shadows, etc.

I thought maybe I could add a plane in between that would work as a one way mask - you can see the orange plane outlined which has a holdout material shader applied to it and backface culling on so I can see through this side, but it didn't stop the ocean still getting a peek.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it possible?

(Update, I've been using Eevee to render this)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *Compositor* or try this kind of node setup for your grid material: Use the *Input > Light Path > Is Reflection Ray* as a factor between the original material and a *Transparent* node (you'll need to give your material a *Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*):

[image]