# Hide an object from reflecting in the ocean modifier using nodes

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, ocean-simulation

I asked [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203563/hide-an-object-from-reflecting-in-the-ocean-modifier) the other day and it got closed as being a duplicate.

The answer that I was directed to did help, but didn't solve the full problem.

To clarify, I followed [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192911/62803) which did nothing and I tried all the different combinations of the Light Path node trying to find one that worked before eventually changing the material from Alpha Hashed to Alpha Blended.

It disappeared from the ocean. I thought I had found the solution but then when I went back to the camera view I realised it was still being reflected in the sun's shine on the ocean.

Here is the issue and the node setup I have:

[image]

(If you look on the original question you will see that initially it was showing all over the ocean)

Is there something I have missed?

[image]

Comment: I first though that was due to the emission, but not the case. Could you upload your file so we can have a look at all the shaders in the scene? Please use this site to do it http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the result link here.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've [uploaded it here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/B20ko14y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192907/rendering-a-fake-mirror/192911#192911) uses a reflexion plane for the mirror. And it seems that *"Screen space reflections"* alone won't produce the wanted ligth path.

Consider adding a *"reflexion plane"* and scale it until it covers the grid reflexion area:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for helping me